# JTextField неправильно отображается

Tags: java, swing

При создании графического интерфейса на Swing (пользуюсь Eclipse) я наткнулся на проблему некорректного отображения JTextField (поле ввода). В консоли никаких ошибок нет (Mac OS 10.15.7, JDK 14.0.2) На Windows 10 такой проблемы не замечал

Примерно так все выглядит: 
[image: 1]

Код:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private JTextField txtGuess;
    public Game() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        txtGuess = new JTextField();
        txtGuess.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        txtGuess.setBounds(279, 62, 70, 26);
        getContentPane().add(txtGuess);
        txtGuess.setColumns(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game theGame = new Game();
        theGame.setSize(new Dimension(435, 262));
        theGame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Из-за чего это так происходит и как это исправить?